# Is this a Fixed Parameter Tractable algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes

Suppose my algorithm runs in time $O(nL^2)$, where $n$ is the size of the input, and $L$ some other parameter, which can get arbitrarily large *w.r.t.* $n$. My algorithm does not run in polynomial time, since $L$ can get arbitrarily large *w.r.t.* $n$. So I'd like to categorize it elsewise.
Fixed Parameter Tractable algorithms, with regards to some defined parameter $k$, run in time $O(f(k)\times n^{O(1)})$, where $f$ is any function.

Would it be correct to state that my algorithm is Fixed Parameter Tractable (FPT) with regards to the parameter $L$?

Comment: If your algorithm is FPT according to the definition of FPT, then it is FPT.

Comment: Your algorithm sounds like it is (psuedo-)polynomial time in $n \cdot L$, hence it is a (pseudo-)polynomial time algorithm.

Comment: @PålGD I think pseudo-polynomial is indeed the most fitting term. Could you post it as an answer? Also, the answer needs to contain why this is not an FPT algorithm (or rather problem). Indeed, your previous answer states it is not an FPT algorithm due to the belief that L was dependent on n. But this has been cleared up, so a new answer is needed.

Comment: @J.Schmidt Whether you should _call_ your algorithm FPT is a slightly different question from whether it _is_ FPT. Do you want an argument why you shouldn't call your algorithm an "FPT algorithm" (or "an algorithm that runs in FPT time")? Because it is one.

Comment: @Discrete lizard Does your saying "Because it is one." reflect on the algorithm being FPT? If so, please add a complete answer below, which I can review and potentially accept.

Comment: Having a parameter that can be arbitrarily large compared to $n$ isn't a problem. However, the parameter should also be able to take values arbitrarily smaller than $n$. Otherwise, the problem (assuming it is computable) is trivially FPT and talking about FPT doesn't make much sense. For instance "Dominating Set in bounded degree graphs" parameterized by the natural parameter (size of the dominating set) is trivially FPT since a graph with degree at most $d$ and a dominating set of size $k$ can only have $n\leq (d+1)k$ vertices. The $2^{O(n)}$ brute-force algorithm is "FPT" in this parameter.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden I think my $L$ is bounded below by $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$, is this small enough, or should it be able to get smaller? Also, could you explain why your brute force algorithm is FPT? Is it possible to denote its running time as $f(k) \times n^{O(1)}$?

Comment: @J.Schmidt I made a full-fledged answer. In this case $2^{O(n)}=2^{O((d+1)k)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider $L$ to be *a parameter*, then yes, you have an *FPT time* algorithm, and your parameterized problem is indeed in the complexity class FPT, but be precise when you define your problem so that it is indeed stated as a parameterized problem.

Although we often refer to things as *FPT algorithms*, it is actually the *problems* that are FPT or not.  Just as we don't have "NP-complete algorithms", we don't really have algorithms that are "FPT".

However, keep in mind that your algorithm also runs in pseduo-polynomial time in $O(n \cdot L^2)$ (if I understand $L$ correctly).  So, since your might not be (weakly) NP-hard, I would state it as a pseudo-polynomial time algotithm.

*(Definition)*.  Your algorithm is *pseudo-polynomial* in $n$ and $L$ since it has running time $O(n \cdot L^2)$ and $L$ is an integer.

Ps:  I claim that it is incorrect to say that we have an FPT algorithm, when it is the *problem* that belongs to FPT, and the algorithm runs in "FPT time".  Of course, I call algorithms "FPT algorithms", too, but when it comes to the way we speak with students, I feel that it is important to make a distinction between problems and algorithms.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your last paragraph. What exactly do you mean by a parameter being fixed? That it should be a constant? That isn't true.. Consider a couple of the common parameters - size of the solution, treewidth - why are these 'fixed'? I also don't understand why 'the number of maximal cliques in $G$' can't be a parameter - that sounds like a perfectly reasonable parameter to me?

Comment: I do not agree with your point against the term "FPT algorithm". An FPT algorithm is an algorithm that solves some problem instance of size $n$ with parameter $k$ in $f(k)\cdot n^{O(1)}$ time, just as a polynomial time algorithm solves some problem instance of size $n$ in $n^{O(1)}$ time. I see no more reason to say that we don't have FPT algorithms than that we don't have polynomial time algorithms. Of course, we have to be careful what the parameter $k$ means in our problem, but the same case holds for the input size $n$ for the poly-time algorithm (see e.g.  pseudo-polynomial time)

Comment: My explanation created some confusion around $L$ being dependent on $n$. I cleared this up, and to clarify : **$L$ does not depend on $n$.** What I meant to say is that $L$ can be arbitrarily large  *w.r.t.* $n$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the effort of editing your answer, however it does not contain why my algorithm (or rather problem) is not FPT. Your answer states it is not an FPT algorithm due to the belief that L was dependent on n. But this has been cleared up, so a new reason is needed.

Comment: @PålGD What is the definition of a "fixed" parameter? The treewidth of graphs is not a "fixed" parameter, in the sense that it can vary from graph to graph, so why can treewidth be used as a valid parameter for FPT problems, but not my $L$? Is it because I stated my $L$ can get arbitrarily large *w.r.t.* $n$, whereas treewidth is usually very small  *w.r.t.* $n$? So is the definition of a "fixed" parameter something that is usually small *w.r.t.* $n$, and if so, how small does it have to be?

Comment: @PålGD Then it doesn't make any sense for my problem not to be FPT *w.r.t.* $L$. Indeed, suppose I give some fixed constant upper bound $L'$ to my algorithm in the hope that the $L$ of the instance is actually below it. This is exactly what you just said, but I replaced treewidth with $L$. If your opinion is still that my problem is not FPT, then why don't you give a solid reason for it? You keep giving definitions, but my problem, and $L$, seem to abide by those definitions...

Comment: Okay, I yield.  I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, I would advise having another look at the basic definitions. An FPT instance is identified by a string $x$ and an integer $k$ such that $(x, k)$ is a yes-instance.

Put briefly, if $f(k)$ is not polynomial in terms of $n$ and still depends on $n$, then you cannot obtain an FPT algorithm. We require that $k$ is fixed, or independent of $n$, and thus $f(k)$ is always independent of $n$. However, if $f(k) = n^{O(1)}$, then our FPT algorithm is in fact a polynomial time algorithm. Hence, if $f(k) = O(2^n)$, the answer is definitely no.

Comment: I see how you come to the conclusion that L depends on n through my explanation, but what I actually meant was L is independent of n, but can be really large w.r.t.. n (I'll change my explanation to reflect this). This is good news though, since, by your explanation, it does mean my algorithm (or rather my problem, as stated in another answer) is in fact FPT, w.r.t. L.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "part of the running time" being the parameter. It is kind of silly since it trivially results in an FPT problem/algorithm, but it's not technically wrong. A parameter is simply a number associated with each instance of the problem. There's nothing wrong with that parameter being equal to (part of) the running time.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I realized this error earlier as well - I shouldn't cook up an answer late at night - but I simply haven't had the time to correct it yet. Ideally I'd like to correct it, but this comment is helpful for those new to fixed parameter tractability. I'm now left wondering whether I should leave my comment as is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is technically correct to call such an algorithm FPT but rather pointless.

Suppose that the problem at hand is computable, say, it can be solved in time $T(n)$.

You write that $L$ is bounded from below by $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$.

Putting these two facts together, we have that the problem can be solved in time $T(c L^2)$ for some constant $c$. Taking $f(k)=T(c k^2)$, this is an FPT running time, since $T(c L^2)=f(L)\times n^0=f(L)\times n^{O(1)}$.

If a parameter $k$ is bounded in any way from below by any function of $n$ (no matter how slow growing), then the problem (assuming it is computable) is automatically fixed-parameter tractable in that parameter. We don't even need the "$n^{O(1)}$-part" of the running time, we can simply solve the problem in $f(k)$ time by computing an upper bound on $n$ from $k$ and then running a brute-force algorithm.

Comment: I've edited your answer to precise what you mean with $T$ in $T(n)$, so that people don't confuse it with $O(n)$, but the edit has been refused for some reason.

Comment: @J.Schmidt The edit was rejected by me and one other person for not improving the answer. It is clear from the context what $T$ is; in my opinion your edit only makes the answer wordier and does not contribute to clarity.